# creating GIS data directly on camera images

Tags: open-source-gis, 3d, remote-sensing, software-recommendations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

If I'm taking few photos with superimposition and enabling a stereo system for images pairs, Is there a software for 3D or 2D calibrating that will enable then creating GIS vector data  directly on regular camera images after anchoring the data ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'creating ... technical drawings' on the image? Do you want to modify the image by adding a vector data overlay?

Comment: I've edit the question

Comment: Could you describe in more detail exactly what you want to see in the final image? Describe an example.

Comment: Are you talking about Hyperlinks ?

Comment: "regular camera images" - are you asking about creating ground data from perspective images (ie street lines from a photo taken by a person standing on the ground or even in a building taking picture down the street)? Or are you talking about making a 3D building from a perspective photo? I know SketchUp has some tools to do this (not stereo pairs) and can be ported into GIS fairly easily. Stereo-orthorectification is a whole other ballgame. You have added a 'drone' tag, so I might suggest visting http://dronemapper.com/

Comment: You have a drone tag but make no mention of drones, UAVs or anything that seems related in your question body. Can you revise it to explain the significance, please?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Agisoft Photoscan ( http://www.agisoft.ru/products/photoscan ) fits your needs.

Comment: thanks til_b -look good but very expensive, is there any open source equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, VisualSFM ( http://ccwu.me/vsfm/ ). But thats more complicated and less comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for open source check out opendronemap, it is growing by leaps and bounds every month: http://opendronemap.github.io/odm/

So far it is capable of:

-Point Clouds

-Digital Surface Models

-Textured Digital Surface Models

-Orthorectified Imagery

Personally I have not tried it but if it makes good point clouds and orthomosaics that is all that is required from there you can do post processing in any number of gis software packages to make 3d and 2d products.

Check out this youtube link to see it in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2qp3o8caPs